# Bringing advisor into summer internship project

Tags: advisor, industry, internship

I have a summer internship in the research side of a big tech company. I already know the project I will be working on, and it has some relation to my advisor's research. In fact I believe he might be more knowledgeable than some of the researchers I will be working with over the summer.

I've already shared what I know of the project with him, and he gave me some general thoughts about it. I'd like to continue getting his input, but signed a form for the company saying I forfeit any results to the company. (I think this just means that they get credit for any resulting papers).

Is it possible/typical for an advisor to get involved in a student's summer internship project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this situation seldom arises, so wouldn't call it typical. There might be university regulations that govern it, since your relationship to your advisor would change somewhat.

But I fear you are being a bit naive about the company's ownership of your results. It probably means that you can't publish without permission (and specific approval). It might mean, or imply, non-disclosure of what you learn. In the latter case, the company would need to establish a formal relationship with your advisor so that everyone understands and adheres to the ground rules.

I don't think there are problems *necessarily*, but you need to make sure that everybody in the process understands what is happening.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about confidentiality. Will figure that out